# filter out the first and second column from file per pattern, in cmd/batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this file and I have to filter out the first and second column from it, per the pattern 'Titan' or others in the same line as the first and second column (the pattern may appear in any other column except the first two).

I gotta do it in windows batch :-(

here's an example file:

```
  d:\sections.txt:

# section1
127.0.0.1 80 Titan
ip1 443 Titan

# software servers 2
ip2 80 software
servername 443 Composer software

C:\Users\user>findstr Titan d:\sections.txt
127.0.0.1 80 Titan
ip1 80 Titan
```

I thought about something along the lines of

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in $(findstr Titan d:\sections.txt) do @echo %i
```

but that doesn't seem to please Microsoft Windows.
Then I tried:

```
findstr Titan d:\sections.txt | for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in (d:/sections.txt) do @echo %%i
```

but I don't know how to do the For loop without the file, and with the output of the findstr.

This command ought to be part of a larger script so I'm trying to keep from outputing to temp files, writing long scripts for a stupid little thing, etc.

Any help would be appreciated, with other tools if necessary. I miss bash..

Comment: Without wishing to be overly rude, based upon what you've provided in your question, your general grasp of the structure of batch script commands isn't very good. For that reason, I'd be more confident if I was to see the entire 'larger' batch script and also an example of what you want your output to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

three little errors in your line.
a) To process the output of a command, enclose the command in single quotes.
b) Either use `%%i` for use in a batch file **or** use `%i` for use on the command line. Do not mix both syntaxes.
c) you said "filter out the first *and second* column", but you use the first token only.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in ('findstr Titan d:\sections.txt') do @echo %%i %%j
```

should be much nearer to what you want.

Comment: Cheers! I was testing in CMD so used %i, but the command runs fine in a Jenkins pipeline bat, with the single quotes. It's the little things that count...